# E/log_tag(1601): Error Parsing Data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse, import

Everytime when I start my program I get this error:

E/log_tag(1601): Error Parsing Data org.json.JSONException: Value !DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

I read so many things about it, but don't know really how I can resolve the problem..
Please hep me!!! Thanks!

java code:

```
package com.example.vertretungsplannonnenwerth;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView resultView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.enableDefaults();
    resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);  


getData();  


}   






public void getData(){
    String result = "";
    InputStream is = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("link");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }

catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Keine Verbindung zur Internetseite"+e.toString());
    resultView.setText("Keine Verbindung zur Datenbank");
    }

try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"),8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null ){
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();

    result=sb.toString();
}
catch (Exception e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Fehler beim Konvertieren" +e.toString());
}
try{
    String s =result;
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);


    for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        s = s +
                "Datum : "+json.getInt("Datum") + "\n" +
                "Stunde : "+json.getInt("Std")+ "\n" +
                "Klasse : "+json.getInt("Klasse")+ "\n" +
                "Fach : "+json.getString("Fach")+ "\n" +
                "Lehrer : "+json.getString("Lehrer")+ "\n" +
                "Vertretung : "+json.getString("Vertretung")+ "\n" +
                "Raum : "+json.getInt("Raum")+ "\n" +
                "Bemerkung : "+json.getString("Bemerkung")+ "\n\n";

    }
    resultView.setText(s);

} 
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Fehler beim Datenabruf"+e.toString());
}




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

php code:

```
$con = mysql_connect("server", "db name", "password");

if (!$con)
     {
     die ('Keine Verbindung zur Datenbank.': mysql_error());
     }
mysql_select_db("db", $con);

$result=mysql_query("SELECT*FROM tbVertretungsplan");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
     {
     $output[]=$row;
     }

print (json.encode($output));

mysql_close($con);


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON string you are trying to convert starts with the word `!DOCTYPE`.
Since the string `!DOCTYPE` is not formatted as a JSON string you get a JSONException.

The link that you are reading data from starts with the HTML tag `<!DOCTYPE html>` ([example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)). Sanitize your data input string and remove any HTML tags and non-JSON strings to make your code work. You can sanitize either in your php code (not sure how to do that with the code you provided), or strip out all tags in your app.

To remove HTML tags (and all other tags) you can use:

```
String noHTML = html.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
```

Comment: Can you print your JSON before parsing it and pasting it in the question?